# JQuery PHP change URL from select box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have single page with div element , that changes color regarding of selected color.
Selection is made using select box.

```
Select color from table_colors where id=($_GET["id"])
```

Current URL :

```
http://localhost/colors.php?id=1
```

My plan is to :

- Choose color green (id=2) from select box.
- Using JQuery , to change href id value
- Refresh page (or just a DIV) to change the color

In my situation It is very important to pass value to URL 
How it is done?

Comment: Put the select in a form and use `method="get"`? But why not get all colors from your DB at once and use jQuery to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said:

```
<form method="get" action=colours.php">
  <select name="id">
    <option value="2">Green</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What if I have multiple elements in URL , I want to change just a id

Comment: colours.php?id1&pl1&cd1 to colours.php?id2&pl1&cd1

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    var colors = {
        "1": "red",
        "2": "green",
        ...
    };

    $("#select").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $("#div").css("color", colors[val]);
        $("#url").attr("href", "http://localhost/colors.php?id="+val);
    });
});
```